# sum string comma separated numbers in lua

Tags: lua, redis

I'm receiveing in a lua script a hash from redis with numbers in a string format.

```
1) "30"
2) "30.7"
3) "12.7"
4) "15.7"
5) "20.7"
6) "19.7"
7) "20.5"
8) "21.5"
9) "22.3"
10) "30.7"
```

I know that Lua does not differentiate between floating point numbers and integers.

This is the script:

```
local sum = "0.0"
local matches = redis.call('KEYS', 'sdid:*')

for _,key in ipairs(matches) do
    local val = redis.call('HGET', key ,'data')
    sum = sum + val
end

return sum
```

I receive the result in integer format ((integer) 224
) how could I receive de result in a real format string "224.5" ?

Comment: Lua 5.3 does differentiate between floating point numbers and integers.

Comment: What is a "comma separated format"? Something like `1,000,000.00` for 10^6 ?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: What string do you want for the result 224? If you want `224.0`, use `string.format("%.1f",sum)`.

Comment: @lhf I want the result with the decimal numbers. I don't know why I'm getting a 224 as result.

Comment: print `val` and `sum` inside the loop to see what's happening.

Comment: I solved it using string.format("%.1f",sum) @lhf

Comment: @JosepBacardit the sum of the values you provided is 193.8 I guess you were missing a number in your question. Please be more careful when you write question to avoid confusion. Also comma separated numbers are separated by commas, not by a dot as in your example.

Comment: Sorry @Ihf I've missed a number. Question updated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In arithmetic operations, Lua automatically converts strings containing numbers to numbers.

So, just add the strings with `a+b+c` and you'll get the number 6.6.

If you want the result with 1 decimal place even if its an integer, use `string.format("%.1f",sum)`.